# Parameters from disabled Joomla module

Tags: joomla, parameters, module

Is it possible to load parameters from a disabled Joomla module in an external PHP file?

Comment: What Joomla version are you using? What have you tried so far? Have you done any research?

Comment: @Lodder is there a difference between the versions in regards ?

Comment: @alfasin -  Not sure about Joomla 1.5 and 2.5, but if it's Joomla 3.x then yes. `JParameter` and `$mainframe` are deprecated.

Comment: Mainframe is deprecated in 2.5 ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('example'); //Get the module (in this case "example")
$moduleParams = new JParameter($module->params); //Retrieve this modules parameters
$param = $moduleParams->get('paramName', 'defaultValue'); //Get the specific parameter
```

This code should retrieve the article parameters whether disabled or not. If it's an external php file in terms of being outside of Joomla you'll also need to load the Joomla classes using:

```
//init Joomla Framework
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..'));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

See [here](http://www.themepartner.com/blog/25/retrieving-plugin-module-component-and-template-parameters/) for more information